# Threejs Merge geometries for performance

Tags: three.js

First of all, I am new to three.js and I am working on a module where I have to show a rotating globe having markers on the globe. I have plotted the markers on the globe and also I have some tooltip and click event on the marker, everything is working fine for small data set but when it comes to plot more than 5000 markers on the globe the fps drops. I want a smooth experience.
I know I can merge the geometries but I can't figure out how to do that.

Suggestions and optimization to get a smooth experience are welcomed. Thank You !!

```
data.forEach((markerData) => {
        if (markerData.geolocation) {
            const lat = markerData.geolocation.latitude;
            const lon = markerData.geolocation.longitude;
            const radius = 0.004;
            let height = 2.5;

            const materialRedLines = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
                color: "#f62e2e",
                linewidth: 1,
                linecap: 'round', 
                linejoin: 'round' 
            });

            let marker = new THREE.Mesh(
                new THREE.CylinderBufferGeometry(
                    radius,
                    0.001,
                    height,
                    30
                ),
                materialRedLines
            );
            marker.position.y = height * 0.5;
            marker.rotation.x = Math.PI;

            const latRad = lat * (Math.PI / 180);
            const lonRad = -lon * (Math.PI / 180);
            const r = 1.0;

            marker.position.set(
                Math.cos(latRad) * Math.cos(lonRad) * r,
                Math.sin(latRad) * r,
                Math.cos(latRad) * Math.sin(lonRad) * r
            );
            marker.rotation.set(0.0, -lonRad, latRad - Math.PI * 0.5);
            this.markerGroup.add(marker); // Group element which i add to the scene
        }
    });
```

Comment: Maybe makes sense to take a look at instancing? [`THREE.InstancedMesh()`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/objects/InstancedMesh) can help. It also supports [raycasting](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_instancing_raycast).

Answer (score 0):

If they are truly static . Make sure you do updateMatrixWorld() on the marker And then set it's .matrixAutoUpdate to false.. that will save a bunch of matrix operation at the cost of some manual housekeeping when you need to change individual markers. If you are going to need way more, you can try instancing or merging. Instancing is a bit more complex conceptually.

Try the matrixAutoUpdate = false trick first and see how much that helps if at all.

Also consider using something simpler than a cylinder, like a three.sprite with a circle texture applied w alpha to get it as a cut out. If you're doing 5000 markers at 30*4 triangles, that's ~600,000 triangles just on markers. Using sprites brings that triangle count down to ~10,000.